# Return default value for generic type

Tags: go, generics, null

How do you return `nil` for a generic type `T`?

```
func (list *mylist[T]) pop() T {
    if list.first != nil {
        data := list.first.data
        list.first = list.first.next
        return data
    }
    return nil
}

func (list *mylist[T]) getfirst() T {
    if list.first != nil {
        return list.first.data
    }
    return nil
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
 cannot use nil as T value in return statement
```

Comment: You can't return `nil` for _any_ type. If `int` is used as the type argument for `T`, returning `nil` makes no sense.

Comment: is there any way to return the default value. Like for a struct return nil for int 0?

Comment: If a zero value is returned, how does the client/caller differentiate between (a) the value is the element, and (b) the list was empty? Since `pop()` or `getfirst()` cannot return an element when they are empty, I would change the return type to `(T, error)` to communicate this potential empty/error condition.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can't return `nil` for *any* type. If `int` is used as the type argument for `T` for example, returning `nil` makes no sense. `nil` is also not a valid value for structs.

What you may do–and what makes sense–is return the [zero value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for the type argument used for `T`. For example the zero value is `nil` for pointers, slices, it's the empty string for `string` and `0` for integer and floating point numbers.

How to return the zero value? Simply declare a variable of type `T`, and return it:

```
func getZero[T any]() T {
    var result T
    return result
}
```

Testing it:

```
i := getZero[int]()
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", i, i)

s := getZero[string]()
fmt.Printf("%T %q\n", s, s)

p := getZero[image.Point]()
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", p, p)

f := getZero[*float64]()
fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", f, f)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/YXeLmVN1TOq?v=gotip)):

```
int 0
string ""
image.Point (0,0)
*float64 <nil>
```

Answer (score 71):

#### The `*new(T)` idiom

This has been suggested as the preferred option in golang-nuts. It is probably less readable but easier to find and replace if/when some zero-value builtin gets added to the language.

It also allows one-line assignments.

The [`new` built-in](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Allocation) allocates storage for a variable of any type and returns a pointer to it, so dereferencing `*new(T)` effectively yields the zero value for `T`. You can use a type parameter as the argument:

```
func Zero[T any]() T {
    return *new(T)
}
```

In case `T` is comparable, this comes in handy to check if some variable is a zero value:

```
func IsZero[T comparable](v T) bool {
    return v == *new(T)
}
```

#### `var` of type `T`

Straightforward and easier to read, though it always requires one line more:

```
func Zero[T any]() T {
    var zero T
    return zero
}
```

#### Named return types

If you don't want to explicitly declare a variable you can use named returns. Not everyone is fond of this syntax, though this might come in handy when your function body is more complex than this contrived example, or if you need to manipulate the value in a `defer` statement:

```
func Zero[T any]() (ret T) {
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Zero[int]())               // 0
    fmt.Println(Zero[map[string]int]())    // map[]  
    fmt.Println(Zero[chan chan uint64]())  // <nil>
}
```

It's not a chance that the syntax for named returns closely resembles that of var declarations.

Using your example:

```
func (list *mylist[T]) pop() (data T) {
    if list.first != nil {
        data = list.first.data
        list.first = list.first.next
    }
    return
}
```

---

##### Return `nil` for non-nillable types

If you actually want to do this, as stated in your question, you can **return `*T` explicitly**.

This can be done when the type param `T` is constrained to something that *excludes pointer types*. In that case, you can declare the return type as `*T` and now you can return `nil`, which is the zero value of pointer types.

```
// constraint includes only non-pointer types
func getNilFor[T constraints.Integer]() *T {    
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(getNilFor[int]()))    // *int
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(getNilFor[uint64]())) // *uint64
}
```

Let me state this again: this works best when `T` is **NOT** constrained to anything that admits pointer types, otherwise what you get is a pointer-to-pointer type:

```
// pay attention to this
func zero[T any]() *T {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(zero[int]()))  // *int, good
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(zero[*int]())) // **int, maybe not what you want...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can init a empty variable.

```
if l == 0 {
        var empty T
        return empty, errors.New("empty Stack")
    }
```