# golang zero value for generic types

Tags: go, generics

I'm testing version 1.18beta2 of golang. I have this function:

```golang
func Do[T any](value T) (T, bool) {
     if guardCondition {
         return nil, false // Complains about "cannot use nil as T value in return statement"
     }
     ... // rest of function
}
```

Which will not complile due to *cannot use nil as T value in return statement* . Normally, you would return a pointer or whichever "nilable" type. However, when using generics no type seems to please de compiler. I cannot find any online resource handling any kind of this example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create "zero" value using `*new(T)` it returns what you would expect.

You can play around with `*new(T)` here - https://go.dev/play/p/7e7zGKMgoRW.

More information - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70589302/4108803.

**Original answer,**

Well, just tried with

```
func Do[T any](value T) (T, bool) {
     if guardCondition {
         var noop T
         return noop, false
     }
     ... // rest of function
}
```

which makes the trick :)

Comment: Kind of sad that there is no better way. I was hoping `make(T)` will work.

Comment: @RobertZaremba use `*new(T)`. [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70589302/4108803)

Comment: new(T) should be the accepted answer