# Print type parameter name in Go

Tags: go, generics

If I write a generic function in Golang, I can print the type of either of the arguments to the function like this, which provides some insight into the type parameter:

```
func foo[T any](a T, b T) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v and %v are of type %T", a, b, a)
}
```

However, if I modify the function to take a slice instead:

```
func foo[T any](args ...T) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v are of type %T", args, args)
}
```

this will not print what I would prefer as calling `foo[int]` will mean that `args` has a type of `[]int` whereas I want to print `int`. I could modify this to print `args[0]` instead but that means I also have to check for the case where `args` is empty and, in that case, I don't have a way to get the type of `args`. I could also use reflection to get the type, but since it's a generic function, I should also know this at compile-time.

Is there a way I can get name of `T` at compile time without having to print the type of any arguments or through reflection?

Comment: The distinction of "at compile time" is pretty meaningless here anyway. In any case, the name of the type must be built into your program as a string, and to access it you must reference that string somehow. Using reflect would only involve following the references from `interface value -> type data object -> name string`. You could implement your own optimization to save a grand total of 1 pointer deference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Printing the type name *at compile time* is not possible. Both `fmt` and `reflect` functions (which `fmt` uses) are run time operations. You might be able to find out the type of some expression with static analysis but again this is orthogonal to run-time printing.

Anyway *at run time*, if the type parameter list captures the base type of a composite type, including a vararg slice, you can simply print it by declaring [a new variable of that type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70589302/4108803). The idiom `*new(T)` in particular allows to do it with one-liners:

```
func foo[T any](args ...T) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%+v are of type %T", args, *new(T))
}
```

Calling that as `foo(1,2,3)` now gives the string:

```
"[1 2 3] are of type int"
```

---

Yes, the compiler is smart enough to know that `*new(T)` doesn't escape to the heap.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way I can get name of T at compile time without having to print the type of any arguments or through reflection?

No

You need reflection for this.