# Get the type name of a generic struct without type parameters

Tags: go, generics

Say I have a generic struct called `foo` and I create two objects from it. I can determine the concrete type of each using `reflect.TypeOf()`, like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type foo[T any] struct {
    data T
}

func main() {
    a := foo[string]{"cheese"}
    b := foo[int]{42}

    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b))
}

// main.foo[string]
// main.foo[int]
```

What I am interested in is determining just the generic type of these objects (i.e., `foo`) and not the concrete type (i.e., `foo[string]` and `foo[int]`). Is this possible or do I need to manually extract the generic type from these strings (e.g., with regex)?

---

#### Edit

Regex might look something like this:

```golang
func GetGenericType(x any) string {
    // Get type as a string
    s := reflect.TypeOf(x).String()

    // Regex to run
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\.(.*)\[`)

    // Return capture
    return r.FindStringSubmatch(s)[1]
}


fmt.Println(GetGenericType(a))
fmt.Println(GetGenericType(b))

// foo
// foo
```

---

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72610728/print-type-parameter-name-in-go) but this doesn't answer this question because it gives the *concrete* type (i.e., `main.foo[string]`) rather than the generic type (i.e., `foo`).

Comment: The problem is that `foo` itself is not a type.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Sorry, I'm new to Go so may have used the wrong word. What is the correct term for what `foo` is? In short, I'd like to see if a type is derived from `foo`.

Comment: Technically it is called a "generic type". Despite how the name sounds, "generic types" are not a subset of regular "types". They are totally distinct, and relatively isolated in the language design. Currently, the only way to reference generic types is through type instantiation, and they have no representation in `reflect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection doesn't see the name of the "base" generic type, because at run time that base type doesn't exist.

The relevant passage from the Go spec is [Instantiations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Instantiations):

> Instantiating a type results in a **new non-generic named type**; instantiating a function produces a new non-generic function.

So when you write:

```
b := foo[int]{42}
name := reflect.TypeOf(b).Name()
```

the name of that type is precisely `foo[int]`.

It's worth noting that the *identifier* `foo` without the type parameter list is relevant at compile time, because it prevents you from redeclaring it in the same package. [Type definitions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions):

> A type definition creates a new, distinct type with the same
> underlying type and operations as the given type and **binds an
> identifier, the type name, to it**.
>
> ```
> TypeDef = identifier [ TypeParameters ] Type .
> ```

But instantiations, as defined above, result in a new named type which is different than `foo`; and at run time when you can use reflection, you deal with instantiations only.

In conclusion, I think [your solution with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74838506) is acceptable, until some helper function is added to the stdlib (if ever). Reposting it here for clarity:

> ```
> func GetGenericType(x any) string {
>     // Get type as a string
>     s := reflect.TypeOf(x).String()
>
>     // Regex to run
>     r := regexp.MustCompile(`\.(.*)\[`)
>
>     // Return capture
>     return r.FindStringSubmatch(s)[1]
> }
> ```

Just keep in mind the difference between `Type.String()` and `Type.Name()`: any type can have a string representation, but only named types have a name. (Obviously, right?). So for example if you wrote:

```
b := &foo[int]{42}
```

then the type of `b` is `*foo[int]`, which is an anonymous composite type, and `Name()` returns an empty string.

Comment: This is a great help. To clarify: is a user-defined type determined using reflection always prefixed by the package name (e.g., `main.foo[int]` as opposed to `foo[int]`)?

Comment: @Lyngbakr yes and no! if you check the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type) of `reflect.Type`, you can see on `Name()` *Name returns the type's name within its package for a defined type*, so this is *not* prefixed. But `String()` says *The string representation may use shortened package names (e.g., base64 instead of "encoding/base64") and is not guaranteed to be unique among types.* — which is (I think) purposefully vague, to avoid constraining the implementation. You might want to craft the regex to be resilient to this.